# Using CancelOutputRead method of Process class, the right way?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

I've stumbled upon following piece of code when I'm debugging a class which starts a child process like this

```cs
process.Start();
//Attached event handlers for ErrorDataReceived and OutputDataReceived events
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
//Some other logic
process.CancelErrorRead();
process.CancelOutputRead();
//Process is still running from here on..
```

I was doing this exercise because the child process stops responding after a while. Removing the last two lines of code resolves the issue, but I couldn't explain the reason for resolution.

MSDN has this

> When you call CancelErrorRead, all in-progress read operations for StandardError are completed and then the event handler is disabled. All further redirected output to StandardError is saved in a buffer

So my question is

What happens to the process when the buffer is full ?

what's the size of the buffer ?

Did the process become unresponsive because the buffer limit is reached and there are no worker threads reading from it ?

How can I confirm my theory ?

I couldn't find much information online, so hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for help.